# How to review those emails we are in TO address bar in outlook software

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007

I am receiving tons of email everyday, I want to know is there any way I filter just those emails that I am in TO address bar? not Those I am in CC address bar?

can we write any code in outlook to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was answer for my question but I dont know why it is deleted. bTW, for doing this we need to create rule. it is so simple just go to RULE in your menu and chose : move message from someone to a folder then you can specify if your name is in TO move the mail to somewhere else.